# How to share ground connection between to microcontrollers connected to a PC

Tags: analog, ground, ground-loop

I have 2 microcontroller evaluation boards and I am trying to make a I2C communication between them.

Both of the boards are connected to the same PC using USB cables. SDA and SCL pins are also connected. Now I want to know how to connect the ground? I mean do I need to connect grounds of the two boards, or since they are powered by same PC which means they have the same ground reference point, an extra ground connection between them makes a loop or something?

I have checked both with and without GND between two boards, and it works, but I do not have access to Scope or something that I can confirm which is the right thing to do:

[image]

Comment: Ground loops.  As you see, very hard to avoid while prototyping.  The answer below is the quick and easy route, and will work for short distances and speeds.  If you really want to handle the situation correctly, then consider some form of digital isolation between the 2 uC's.  This of course has it's own drawbacks (costing more and limiting bandwidth).  Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine, you only get a ground loop when grounds are not at the same potential. You do need to connect both grounds, but as you're using USB connections from the same PC, you potentially (see below) don't need any further wiring.

As pointed out in the comments, there is potential for noise to cause differing ground potentials and hence spurious/corrupted signals. So, best practice would be to include the wire (as you've drawn) so both microcontroller grounds are connected by a low impedance connection.

Comment: Any reason to downvote this? There's not much more to add...

Comment: well, your answer is correct for ideal cabling and DC only. With high-frequency noise, there can be an arbitrarily high offset between the two grounds at either I²C termination.

Comment: True, but given the information and scenario (and by inference the OP's level of understanding) it's reasonable. Short USB cables to dev boards, and relatively low frequency signals is as close to ideal as you're going to get...

Comment: The point missed is that both MCU's may be powered over USB. In this case there will be noise created by the current draw of each unit. The ground connection between the MCU's is essential IMO, and you should not depend only on the USB ground path.

Comment: I would disagree it's essential, but agree it's probably good practice. Edited to reflect that, thanks for the feedback @JackCreasey :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand current takes the lowest impedance path. In my case lowest impedance in ground will be the short jumper cable between two boards. Is that the case in my context?

Comment: I wish I had an scope and could check amount of noise or offset from GND with and without jumper between boards :(

Comment: @DEKKER Yes, that's correct. Adding the wire provides a low impedance connection and so your ground potentials will be equal.