# Common grounding between two microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, voltage, uart, ground

I am trying to get two microcontrollers to communicate. One is a Tiva-C TM4C123GH6PM (3.3 V.) The other is an Arduino (5 V.) I will use UART.

Should the grounds of the two microcontrollers be connected to each other? Why is a common ground needed?

Comment: How are these boards powered?

Comment: Yes, common ground is needed. Usually there is a ground line pilled along the TX/RX lines. It has is not always safe though, as if both devices are floating, hot-plugging this line might result in a current surge to equalize the two grounds to the same potential, which might very well burn things.

Comment: @MituRaj Both of them connected to computer with their cable. I mean they get power with their connection cable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share ground connection between to microcontrollers connected to a PC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339530/how-to-share-ground-connection-between-to-microcontrollers-connected-to-a-pc)

Comment: @MituRaj That one has a single downvoted answer :)

Comment: @MituRaj Partly yes. I try to understand to making common ground logic, why we need to connect them together. Is it because not all GND are potentially 0V?

Comment: @KerimTurak You need to connect them so both have the same reference point for the signal voltages. If they haven't, the 3.3v one device is sending might be "felt" as 200v by the other device.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted.  Btw +1 from me ;) .. @Eugene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is a common ground needed?

'Ground' is the reference point in a circuit which is assumed as 0V. Voltages at different nodes are quantified with respect to this ground point.

So if two microcontrollers are 'talking' to each other serially in terms of signals, then both micro-controllers should have a common reference point to 'understand' or 'agree upon' what's the voltage level of the signal coming from the other micro-controller. If one sends 3.3V, the other one needs to read it as 3.3V itself.

So yea, they should have a common ground.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you certainly need to have a common ground connection for any physical layer that isn't designed to be galvanically isolated, such as Ethernet.